# class loading exception from module directory in wildlfy

Tags: spring, wildfly, mybatis, ibatis, wildfly-10

Im using org.apache.cxf.jaxrs package in my code which needs to supported from module directory of wildfly,which is not happening and throws dependency missing exception

I tried including the same jar in the ear and faced class not found excpetion as there are two jars with the same package

how to deal with this in wildfly 10, any help would be great

Comment: Any particular reason that you're not using standard JAX-RS api's that come with Java EE 7 (and implemented by WildFly 10)?

Comment: thers is no any specific reason, just got the wildfly structure from another project and trying to alter that only. Please tel me how to go on with java ee 7 apis